# Marcar checkbox se usuário escrever no input text em uma tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso quando o usuário escrever em um input text, ***a checkbox da respectiva linha da tabela*** deve ser marcada, e se caso o usuário deixar o `input text` novamente em branco, a checkbox se desmarca. Segue o código:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="produtostab">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantidade</th>
            <th>Selecionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="inputq1" name="inputquant" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="inputq1" name="inputquant[]" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add" class="btn btn-default">Adicionar</button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygotd5qf/)

Como vocês podem ver, será uma tabela com múltiplas linhas, então não adianta o usuário escrever em um `input` e marcar todos os `checkbox`, é necessário **marcar apenas os das respectivas linhas que os `input`s forem preenchidos**. Acredito que isso deva ser feito com JavaScript, mas como?

Este é o PHP que cria o HTML:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sindigrejinha') or die('Falha ao conectar-se com DB');
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'UTF8'") or die("ERROR: " . mysqli_error($con));
$result = $conn -> query("select idProduto, Descricao from produto");
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($idProduto, $Descricao);
    $idProduto = $row['idProduto'];
    $Descricao = $row['Descricao'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $Descricao . '</td>';
    echo '<td><input name="inputquant[]" type="text" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="'. $idProduto .'" name="checkboxvar[]"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Eu queria remover o código PHP pois o problema é puro JS/HTML, mas como tem uma resposta que fala de PHP, não deu...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugiro adaptar levemente seu HTML, incluindo uma classe (digamos: `CaixaMagica`) em cada caixa de texto e uma classe em cada checkbox. Seu HTML vai ficar parecido com isso:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="CaixaMagica" name="inputquant" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="CheckboxMagico" type="checkbox" value="idProduto" name="checkboxvar" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="CaixaMagica" name="inputquant" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="CheckboxMagico" type="checkbox" value="idProduto" name="checkboxvar" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Depois disto, basta utilizar este código:

```
$(function(){
    $(".CaixaMagica").keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".CheckboxMagico").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".CheckboxMagico").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: esqueci do [JSFiddle que eu preparei](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/qku4q3qj/1/).

Comment: é exatamente o que eu mandei hehehehehe claro exemplo melhor elaborado mas o resultado é o mesmo precisa de adaptação para a necessidade dele somente hehehehe muito bom

Comment: Entendo. Funciona legal, mas só se a input de texto e a checkbox estiverem no mesmo `<td>`. No meu caso, elas precisam ficar em `<td>`s diferentes, como é visto no código que eu passei. Desculpe a ignorância, mas meu conhecimento em javascript é muitíssimo limitado mesmo.

Comment: Coloca seu código no fiddle assim podemos ajudar mais

Comment: @Otto, é claro que há muita semelhança, mas juro que não copiei do seu exemplo; eu estava preparando meu teste quando você respondeu.

Comment: Beleza, coloquei no jsfiddle, mas tive que adaptar, afinal aqui ele está montando a tabela através de um banco de dados. Já atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: @RuiPimentel sem problemas hehehe

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta. Acredito que você consiga adaptá-la, agora :)

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou agora. Agradeço ao Rui Pimentel e ao Otto pela ajuda aí! Muito obrigado haha

Comment: Queisso, sempre bom ajudar :D

Comment: Rui, uma sugestão, no lugar de chamar `.parent()` múltiplas vezes até chegar a `td`, utilize `.closest("td")`.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo! :D valeu, não sabia dessa!!!! ^^

Answer (score 2):

Acho que assim fica pratico de entendimento

```
$( "#input-a-monitorar" ).keyup(function() {
  $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
  $('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Fico a disposição para mais informações

Comment: Cara, não funcionou. Tentei colocar o script dentro da tag `<head>` antes de `<body>`, antes e depois da tabela, tentei mudar `input-a-monitorar` para o id, name e class do meu input text e também a `mycheckbox` para o id, name e class do meu checkbox. Nada funcionou, eu escrevo no input text e nenhum checkbox é marcado. Talvez eu esteja fazendo algo errado, mas não sei o que.

Comment: mas lembrando coloca o que eu te mandei dentro do $( document ).ready(function()  para funcionar certinho tanto que coloquei opção checked true e false para exemplificar se quiser colocar o codigo que voce fez no fiddle ficarei feliz em lhe ajudar ou publique ele em qualquer lugar para testes

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="input" name="inputquant" type="text" />
```

Colocando uma classe no input de texto, o js ficaria assim:

```
$(function(){
    $(".input").keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val()){
            $("input[type=checkbox]",$(this).parents("tr")).attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("input[type=checkbox]",$(this).parents("tr")).removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Espero que isso possa ajudar.

Comment: Leonardo, o parents irá continuar a buscar elementos `tr` mesmo após encontrar a primeira `tr`, então caso haja tabelas dentro de tabelas, o seu código pode introduzir um bug. Então o ideal seria usar o `.closest()`, até por ser mais rápido.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você quer que quando ele digite uma quantidade para um produto, o checkbox armazene o ID deste produto para que depois você possa fazer referência a qual produto foi inserido a quantidade.

Se for, aconselho uma pequena modificação que vai funcionar de forma mais otimizada no seu *script* PHP, no momento que for recuperar os dados.

No momento que monta o HTML, faça esta alteração:

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($idProduto, $Descricao);
    $idProduto = $row['idProduto'];
    $Descricao = $row['Descricao'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $Descricao . '</td>';
    echo '<td><input name="inputquant['.$idProduto.']" type="text" /></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="'. $idProduto .'" name="checkboxvar[]"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

A diferença está no trecho `name="inputquant['.$idProduto.']"`, deste forma você acessa a quantidade de um produto usando a ID do produto como índice do array.

Da forma como o problema foi elaborado, o checkbox está sendo um monitorador do campo quantidade, por isso faço esta sugestão. Inclusive, em um exemplo que deram, realmente resolve o problema dele, mas caso o usuário marque o *checkbox* sem ter preenchido nada no `input`, irá passar uma informação errada para o *script*.